# Android Wallpaper Engine - How to override control buttons

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx, live-wallpaper

I have to **override** control buttons to add some logic there. Take a look at picture below:

[image: control buttons]

For instance, I need to do something before user applies live wallpaper, but just after he presses on the "**set as wallpaper**" or "**settings**" button.

Just for notification: I use LibGDX to create live wallpaper, so it would be great if someone told how to do it in this engine.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can not override it since it is a system app Activity, ie. "com.android.wallpaper.livepicker/.LiveWallpaperPreview"